# Python: wait for input on mouse or timeout

Tags: python, pygame

I am building a photobooth, within this one i aim in having the following process:
(show instructions and wait untill mouse press on OK area) --> RUN PHOTOBOOTH --> DISPLAY PICTURE : either PRINT the picture OR take another photo (timeout of xx sec to return to main menu)

I have the following code on the displaying picture side, and either i pause the code to see the image, or the image displays but no mouse clicks are being captured

```
def PreviewMontage(MontageFile):
    global LastTap
    LastTap = time.time()
    print("Session ID:", SessionID)
    print("Show something.")
    preview = pygame.image.load(MontageFile)
    PILpreview = Image.open(MontageFile)
    previewSize = PILpreview.size # returns (width, height) tuple
    #added /1.5
    ScaleW = AspectRatioCalc(previewSize[0]/1.5, previewSize[1]/1.5, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    preview = pygame.transform.scale(preview, (ScaleW, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    SetBlankScreen()
    background.blit(preview, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2-ScaleW/2, 0))
    PrintScreen()
    #inserting conditions here - get mouse
    camera.stop_preview()
    UpdateDisplay()
    Wait()
    #sleep(20)
    return

def PrintScreen():
    #defines the text of the printscreen and buttons
    #insert button for printing 
    pygame.draw.rect(background, rgbGREEN, pygame.Rect(NEXT_X, 0, ZONEWIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    #restarting button
    pygame.draw.rect(background, rgbRED, pygame.Rect(PREV_X, PREV_Y, ZONEWIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
    ##text
    Text = "Print or restart?"
    Text = smallfont.render(Text, 1, rgbRED)
    textpos = Text.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx = background.get_rect().centerx
    height = Text.get_height()
    background.blit(Text,(textpos)) #Write the small text
    return
# End of function.
```

I have tried this code to wait for input (accepting only input from the left or right side of the touch screen) - it's working but i can't seem to have a reliable timeout:

```
    def Wait():
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
waiting = True

while waiting:
    #clock.tick(time)
    time = 60
    #dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000  # Takes the time between each loop and convert to seconds.
    #time -= dt
    time = time -1 
    #print("Wainting..", waiting, "time ", time)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFTMOUSEBUTTON:
            x, y = event.pos
            print("You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
            LeftMouseButtonDown(x, y)


    if time == 0:
        waiting = False

return
```

The Time variable does not substract... Any ideas on a timeout concept?

Here is the "master loop":

```
while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = 0
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFTMOUSEBUTTON:
        x, y = event.pos
        print("You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
        LeftMouseButtonDown(x, y)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_F4:
            print('F4 pressed, quitting.')
            QuitGracefully()
```

And here is the mouse detection (which i can't get to work on my preview function):

```
def LeftMouseButtonDown(xx, yy):
    # Detect Taps in Previous Zone
    if xx >= PREV_X and xx <= ZONEWIDTH:
            TapPrev()
#     Detect Taps in Next Zone  
    if xx >= NEXT_X and xx <= SCREEN_WIDTH:
            TapNext()
    # Detect Taps in the Start Zone
    if xx >= START_MIN_X and yy >= START_MIN_Y and xx <= START_MAX_X and yy <= START_MAX_Y:
            TapStart()
    # Detect Taps in the Up Zone.
    elif xx >= UP_MIN_X and yy >= UP_MIN_Y and xx <= UP_MAX_X and yy <= UP_MAX_Y:
        KonamiCode('Up')
    # Detect Taps in the Down Zone.
    elif xx >= DOWN_MIN_X and yy >= DOWN_MIN_Y and xx <= DOWN_MAX_X and yy <= DOWN_MAX_Y:
        KonamiCode('Down')
    # Detect Taps in the Left Zone.
    elif xx >= LEFT_MIN_X and yy >= LEFT_MIN_Y and xx <= LEFT_MAX_X and yy <= LEFT_MAX_Y:
        KonamiCode('Left')
    # Detect Taps in the Right Zone.
    elif xx >= RIGHT_MIN_X and yy >= RIGHT_MIN_Y and xx <= RIGHT_MAX_X and yy <= RIGHT_MAX_Y:
        KonamiCode('Right')
    else:
        KonamiCodeReset()
        print("No Event")
    return
# End of function.
```

Comment: How you could make a function that waits for input: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41303079/6486738

Comment: Just tried the funciton, updated the post ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how events are handled in pygame.

---

### How to fix the `wait` function

The reason your `wait` method gives the error `'int' object is not iterable` is because you're trying to loop over an integer. The `event.type` in `for event.pos in event.type:` is an integer representing what type of event it is (the `event` variable is read from your main loop). Instead, you want to iterate (loop) through all events that has happen since you last checked. This can be done by calling the event queue: `for event in pygame.event.get():`.

Then you need to check if the event was the type of event that you want to break out of the loop. I don't know what `KonamiCode('Left')` does, but they doesn't use the events you iterate through so I doubt they'll work. Instead, check `if event.type == x` where `x` is the type of event you want to exit the loop.

**EDIT:** A quick fix to your updated function might look something like this:

```
def wait(time):
    """
    Makes the program halt for 'time' seconds or until the user press the left mouse button.
    """
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    waiting = True

    while waiting:
        dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000  # Takes the time between each loop and convert to seconds.
        time -= dt
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFTMOUSEBUTTON:
                x, y = event.pos
                print("You pressed the left mouse button at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)
                LeftMouseButtonDown(x, y)

        if time <= 0:
            waiting = False

    return  # There is no need for explicit return
```

---

### Tips

Some tips for you to improve your code.

1. In your main loop: `event = pygame.event.poll()` will return just a single event from the event queue. You could instead call `pygame.event.get()` which will return all events since last it was called, and then iterate through the events (as explained above and in the links.
2. Try refactor your functions so they only do one simple thing at a time. For example, `PreviewMontage` loads an  image, scales it, blits it to background, creates a text, blits the text, updates the display and wait for 30 seconds (or milliseconds). It's a bit much and makes the code less reusable and less readable.
3. Using common naming conventions such as `lower_case` for variables and functions, and `CamelCase` for classes, helps other readers to easier identify names and thus easier understand and read the code.

Comment: Thank you so much, i corrected the [wait] and [PreviewMontage] functions adding a [pygame.event.get()] to the [wait] function, and refactoring the [PreviewMontage] function. Now all i can't get working is a timout for the user to interact with the program or it will automatically go back to the beginning....

Comment: How do you mean? Could you explain a bit more and show me your code? https://hastebin.com/ is a simple website were you can just paste your code, save and share the URL, or if you have it on Github. Alternatively, edit your question to contain the updated code.

Comment: I'd like to add a timeout on the PreviewMontage, either the user interacts (given a certain amount of time) with the program, either it resets itself to idle (begining screen). the full code : https://hastebin.com/qucacomuqu.py

Comment: @did12345 I've look into your code and it's a bit hard for me to follow. Instead I updated my answer to include a quick fix to your wait-function. You had two problems: 1. You had `time = 60` in the `while`-loop which meant you were resetting the time every iteration. 2. `if time == 0` does not work if `time` is a float (which it is in this case). The reason is because a floating point number rarely is `0` but rather something like `0.0003525` or `-0.001124`. So seldom will the condition ever be `True`. Instead check for when `if time <= 0`, so you're sure the condition will be true eventually